# External template using backbone.marionette

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, marionette

Using Backbone.View I used to get external template in this way (1)

What if I would like to get the template from external file using Backbone.Marionette.Layout? (2)

---

(1)

```
define(['myTemplate.html'], function (myTemplate) {
    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function ()
        {
            this.$el.html(myTemplate, this.getView());
        }
    });

    return MyView;
});
```

---

(2)

```
define(['myTemplate.html'], function (myTemplate) {
    var Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

        template: "#container",

        regions: {
            top: "#top",
            main: "#main"
        }
    });

    return Layout;
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs

`this.$el.html(myTemplate, this.getView());` btw, does it works?

Comment: user1248256 - can you provide that as an answer instead of a comment, so it can be accepted as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs

```
this.$el.html(myTemplate, this.getView());
```